# Eigendecomposition of a real symmetric matrix obtained by "projection"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, projection

I have a real square matrix $s\times s$ that writes
$$ M = PU\Lambda U^\top P^\top $$
with $P = \left( \mathrm{I}_s ,0\right)\in \mathbb{R}^{s\times r}$, $U \in \mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ orthogonal, and $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ diagonal (with only positive values on the diagonal).

It is clear for me that this matrix is symmetric and real, so it admits an eigendecomposition such that
$$ M = QDQ^\top$$
With $Q$ square orthogonal and $D$ diagonal.

I tried to express $Q$ and $D$ according to the previous decomposition but nothing came up.
Has anyone an idea about this ?

Thank you !